# Why is the game ending a draw when player wins in python Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tic-tac-toe

I've been creating a tic-tac-toe game, the game works fine. The player can win, lose and tie. The problem is when all 9 tiles have been used and there's a win or loss, the draw messagebox appears after the win or loss messagebox. I am using a click count to handle the draw, when the click count reaches 9 i want it to be a tie which does works. However, if there is a win or loss on the 9 turn i want it to only say win or loss without the tie message following.

```
def btn_click(row, col):
    global hasClicked, clickCount

    if buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] == "" and hasClicked == True:
        
        buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] = "X"
        clickCount += 1
            
        #now check for win
        if who_wins("X"):
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You win, Congratulations!")
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
            disable_buttons()
            
        else:
            computer_turn()
            if who_wins("O"):
                messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You lose, Unlucky!")
                messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
                
        if clickCount == 9:
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "It was a Draw!")
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
```

[Gif of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TojT8.gif)

Comment: Well sure, you said `if clickcount==9: ..."it was a draw"`, without other condition that this `clickcount==9`. What else were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. After the `if...else` block, execution will still continue to execute the next `if` statement.

Make sure this code is in a function that you can exit, and use `return`:

```
        if who_wins("X"):
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You win, Congratulations!")
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
            disable_buttons()
            return  # <--
        else:
            computer_turn()
            if who_wins("O"):
                messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You lose, Unlucky!")
                messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
                return # <-- 
                
        if clickCount == 9:
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "It was a Draw!")
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
            return # <--
```

Or if this code appears in a loop, you can opt to use `break`. It all depends on the larger context around this code.

NB: It is not clear why you would only call `disable_buttons()` when "X" wins. Shouldn't this happen when "O" wins as well?

You could also introduce a boolean for registering whether the game has ended, like so:

```
        gamover = who_wins("X")
        if gameover:
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You win, Congratulations!")
        else:
            computer_turn()
            gameover = who_wins("O"):
            if gameover:
                messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "You lose, Unlucky!")
        if not gameover and clickCount == 9:
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "It was a Draw!")
            gameover = True
        if gameover: 
            messagebox.showinfo("O-X-O", "Go to Menu to play again or quit!")
            disable_buttons()
```